# How we setup cakephp 3.x without database?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, nginx, pdo

In our project we don't need a database, so how do we setup cakephp 3.x on a local machine without modifying the database config? I have this issue when I'm running my site.

> Error: Class 'PDO' not found 
>   File /usr/share/nginx/dchannel/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Type.php 
>   Line: 100

So please suggest a better way to do disable the database on cakephp 3.x

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post code you tried so far so we can help you debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically that should be possible if you just avoid to touch anything that interacts with the datbase, or uses PDO related constants and stuff, like the `Type` classes that are by default involved in the applications bootstrap:

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.5.0/config/bootstrap.php#L174-L189**

Also you cannot use Migrations or DebugKit, as both require PDO:

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.5.0/config/bootstrap.php#L206-L207**
**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.5.0/config/bootstrap.php#L211-L217**

If you comment these snippets, and do not touch the model layer anywhere, then it should work. However I don't think that there is a guarantee that this will continue to work. If you want to make sure you can ask the core devs over at **[Slack](https://cakesf.herokuapp.com/)** or **[IRC](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=cakephp)**, or maybe even open a ticket on **[GitHub](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues)**.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible because cakephp use its own design template. so just replace the template with your one .
php default template **\src\Template\Pages\home.ctp**

Comment: You have a point. I removed everything database-related from the default `home.ctp` and disabled the DebugKit plugin, and it no longer shows the database-related error

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to set up CakePHP without a database; it is basically a frontend to a database so the tool doesn't work without one, and I think it also uses it to store some of its configuration.  If you don't need a database, then I advise you choose a different framework.

Comment: I agree with @Lorna. But maybe you can changed the Design template of CakePHP to use something as YAML files to store data. CakePHP has already defined this Symfony bundle in the core. Over all I think when you don't need a database you have to take a look to another framework that's file-based instead of database based.